# border issue on frameless window with rounded edges (pyqt5)

Tags: pyqt, pyqt5, border, rounding, edges

I made a frameless window and added a function to round the edges.
However, when I add a border to the window trough a style sheet, the border doesn't show on the edges like shown [here](https://prnt.sc/ou63i2).

Minimal example:

```
class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setWindowFlags(Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
        self.setFixedSize(300, 380)
        self.round_corners()

    def round_corners(self):
        radius = 9.0
        path = QtGui.QPainterPath()
        path.addRoundedRect(QtCore.QRectF(self.rect()), radius, radius)
        mask = QtGui.QRegion(path.toFillPolygon().toPolygon())
        self.setMask(mask)
```

Stylesheet:

```
QMainWindow
{
    background: #002025;
    border: 1px solid #093038;
}
```

I appreciate any ideas on how to fix that.

Comment: You could try adding `border-radius: 9px;` to the style sheet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try it:

```
from PyQt5.QtCore    import Qt, QSize, QTimer
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QDialog, QVBoxLayout, QWidget,
                            QPushButton, QGridLayout, QSpacerItem,
                            QSizePolicy, QLabel, QApplication)


class Dialog(QDialog):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Dialog, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.setObjectName('Custom_Dialog')
        self.setWindowFlags(self.windowFlags() | Qt.FramelessWindowHint | Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint)
        self.setAttribute(Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground, True)
        self.setStyleSheet(Stylesheet)

        self.initUi()

    def initUi(self):
        # Important: this widget is used as background and rounded corners.
        self.widget = QWidget(self)
        self.widget.setObjectName('Custom_Widget')
        layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.widget)

        # Add user interface to widget
        layout = QGridLayout(self.widget)
        layout.addItem(QSpacerItem(
            40, 20, QSizePolicy.Expanding, QSizePolicy.Minimum), 0, 0)
        layout.addWidget(QPushButton(
            'r', self, clicked=self.accept, objectName='closeButton'), 0, 1)
        layout.addWidget(QLabel("<h2 style='color:blue;'>Hello, world!</h2>"), 2, 0, 5, 2, alignment=Qt.AlignCenter)                           

    def sizeHint(self):
        return QSize(300, 380)        


Stylesheet = """
#Custom_Widget {
    background: #002025;
    border-radius: 20px;
    opacity: 100;
    border: 2px solid #ff2025;                   
}
#closeButton {
    min-width: 36px;
    min-height: 36px;
    font-family: "Webdings";
    qproperty-text: "r";
    border-radius: 10px;
}
#closeButton:hover {
    color: #ccc;
    background: red;
}
"""


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Dialog()
    w.exec_()
    QTimer.singleShot(200, app.quit)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

Comment: @S.Nick this seems a bit of an overkill. Setting the border radius in the stylesheet (as suggested by @Heike) is usually enough; what is the reason for this particular approach, instead? Also, note that on some systems (specifically, some Linux window managers, but I've some doubts about older versions of MacOS and Windows) this specific solution has issues with window positioning and background painting, if the system doesn't support compositing (or it's disabled). PS: what's the reason for the QTimer at the end?